# Use reCaptcha on localhost

Tags: recaptcha

I added localhost and 127.0.0.1 to domains and I added the correct keys but I get this error:
ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do):

> With the following test keys, you will always get `No CAPTCHA` and all
> verification requests will pass.
>
> - Site key: `6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI`
> - Secret key: `6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe`
>
> The reCAPTCHA widget will show a warning message to claim that it's
> only for testing purpose. Please do not use these keys for your
> production traffic.